# Rails ActionView::Template::Error undefined method `count' Resolver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resolver

*Note: I am using ruby 2.5.1 and rails 4.2.10*

I am getting an error in my rails project and I believe it is because one of my classes is called `Resolver`. Here are the relevant files:

**Migration**

```
class CreateResolvers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :resolvers do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.string :name
    end
  end
end
```

**Class**

```
class Resolver < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Controller**

```
class ResolversController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ent = Entity.new(entity_params)
    ent.save!
    redirect_to '/getting_started/resolvers'
  end

  def update
    resToUpdate = Resolver.find(params['id'])
    resToUpdate.update(resolver_params)
    redirect_to '/getting_started/resolvers'
  end

  private

  def resolver_params
    params.require('resolver').permit(
        :name
    )
  end
end
```

So here is my error: When I go into the rails console and do `Resolver.count`, it works fine, but in my actual html page, I have the line:

`<% if (Resolver.count > 0) %>`

and I am getting an error of:

`undefined method 'count' for ActionView::Resolver:Class`

Now, obviously that `ActionView::Resolver:Class` is not correct. I tried changing them to `::Resolver` and `ActiveRecord::Base::Resolver` and neither worked. How can I use a class named `Resolver` without rails assuming it is this `ActionView::Resolver`

Answer (score 2):

Having queries in the view is an antipattern.

The correct way of doing it anyway is to do it in the controller and pass the variable to the view.

`@resolvers_count = Resolver.count` and in the view check on `if @resolvers_count > 0`

a better way is

`@resolvers_exist = Resolver.exists?` and then `if @resolvers_exist`

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it better to define a instance variable at the controller like
`@resolver_count = Resolver.count` so you can reach the count by calling `@resolver_count` on your view?